# How to Set a Value to a Sub-Property Item using TypInfo RTTI Methods?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-2006

In my Question:
[How to use “Sender” parameter with “As” operator for more then one class at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335829/how-to-use-sender-parameter-with-as-operator-for-more-then-one-class-at-a-ti)

I choose the Remy Lebeau's Answer because it was the most dynamic tech for most situations like that. It uses the RTTI TypInfo Class.

But as I was using this class, another problem came:
**How do we Set a sub-property value?**

```
function TRemote.UpdateQuery(DataSet: TDataSet; SQL: String): Boolean;
var
  PropInfo: PPropInfo;
begin
{ atualiza o código SQL padrão de um dataSet de consulta tipo View }
  PropInfo := GetPropInfo(DataSet, 'SQL', []);
  if not Assigned(PropInfo) then
  begin
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    DataSet.Close;
    SetPropValue(DataSet, PropInfo, SQL);
    DataSet.Open;
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Example:
I have a TIBQuery and I want to update the text of the SQL property.
But the SQL property is a TStrings class, so I have to use SQL.Text.
In the code above, It will raise an error "Invalid Property Type" because I got a TStrings and later I try to Set a normal String.

**How to reach the SQL.Text using GetPropInfo?**
Is there a common ancestor of TIBQuery and TZQuery that has the SQL property, so I can change to, instead of the TDataSet in the function parameter?

Comment: Can't you just create a local string list, `SQLstrings := TStringList.Create`, then do `SQLstrings.Text := SQL`, and finally pass `SQLstrings` to `SetPropValue`?

Comment: The `SQL` instance you can get simply with `TStrings(GetObjectProp(DataSet, 'SQL'))`. Are you sure you need to use the `GetPropInfo` ? It will be *unreadable* piece of code.

Comment: Requesting a property by `String` instead of by `PPropInfo` will raise an exception if the property cannot be found.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tried, but the compiler says that we can't use TStrings with SetPropValue.

Comment: You need to use `SetObjectProp()` instead. `SetPropValue()` does not supports objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TStrings.Text` property is not accessible via RTTI in Delphi 2006.  Even if it were, you do not need to use RTTI to access it anyway.  Since you know the `SQL` property is a `TStrings` object, you can simply retreive the actual object pointer from the property and type-cast it to a `TStrings` pointer, then you can do whatever you need to do with that object, eg:

```
function TRemote.UpdateQuery(DataSet: TDataSet; SQL: String): Boolean; 
var 
  PropInfo: PPropInfo; 
  SQLObj: TStrings;
begin 
  Result := False; 
  try 
    PropInfo := GetPropInfo(DataSet, 'SQL', [tkClass]); 
    if not Assigned(PropInfo) then Exit; 
    SQLObj := TStrings(GetObjectProp(DataSet, PropInfo, TStrings));
    if not Assigned(SQLObj) then Exit; 
    DataSet.Close; 
    SQLObj.Text := SQL; 
    DataSet.Open; 
    Result := True; 
  except 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: +1; @EASI, I know you've asked this specifically, but you can use directly `GetObjectProp`. There's no advantage of using `GetPropInfo` before (it is called inside of the other `GetObjectProp` overload).

Comment: Calling `GetPropInfo()` before `GetObjectProp()` allows you to avoid an exception being raised if the property is not found. The other overloaded version of `GetObjectProp()` does not give you that option, it will raise an exception. Which I guess is OK in this case due to the `try/except`, but in general, if you can avoid an exception, you avoid the overhead that goes with it.

Comment: This is great. I've completely forgot to see `GetObjectProp`. This is very educative!

Comment: I did not found the common Ancestor for `TIBQuery` and `TZQuery` (from ZeosLib) but I remembered to use the `Params` property. So I don't need to use SQL property at all. I just need to set the :Parameters in the correct place and them alter it's contents by `DS.ParamByName('ActivityType').AsString := ...`